# calling function within validate function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call a function inside a form validation function, but it's not working.  The function confirm_submit should be called if valid is true.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false, 
  buttons : {
   "Confirm" : function() {
    $('#form').submit();
        },
    "Cancel" : function() {
     $(this).dialog("close");
  }
 }
});


function confirm_submit(){
      $("#dialog").dialog('open');
}

});


function validate(){
valid = true;

if ( document.form.number.value == ""){
    alert ( "You need to complete the Number field." );
    valid = false;
    return valid;
}

if(valid){
confirm_submit();
}
}
```

Comment: Could you describe _how_ it doesn't work? That's much more informative than just saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: The function confirm_submit is not being called.  If I  have $("#dialog").dialog('open'); outside of confirm_submit function, the dialog opens OK.

Comment: I have also tried return confirm_submit(); leaving out the if valid condition..

Comment: Note that if I replace the if(valid){...} etc with a normal confirmation alert e.g.  return confirm('Confirm submit'); that works OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your definition for `confirm_submit` is scoped inside your `document.ready` event. Move the definition after `});` right above `function validate(){`.

This is basically what you're doing:

```
function x() {

    function y() {
        console.log('y')
    }   

    console.log('x');
    y();
}

function z() {
    console.log('z');
    y(); // throws: ReferenceError: y is not defined
}
```

Comment: Yep, that works, now the dialog opens OK, but the forms just submits....I guess that's another problem for now.